# (K)ubuntu 22.04 - Microphones seem to be muted

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I've got a problem with my new computer (Fujitsu Lifebook u7412). I first installed Ubuntu 22.04 and later changed to Kubuntu 22.04. On both, I've got the same issue.
My microphones don't work. All my devices are recognized, but the microphone is still muted. (At least I didn't get any input signal from my various inputs).
I have a mic symbol on my keyboard, but nothing happens after pressing the button.

I found some solutions with adjusting the codec. But

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
```

gives

```
Codec: Realtek ALC257
Codec: Intel Alderlake-P HDMI
```

Under https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html I found 3 possible codecs, but none of them work.

Any suggestions to fix my issue? Thanks!

EDIT:

My bluetooth-headset is working. What is the problem with my wired connections...?